# What is the default px, pt for font-size :small?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

What is the default px, pt for `font-size:small` ?

```
.navigation li a{
font-weight:400;
font-family: "Segoe UI",Segoe,Tahoma,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
**font-size:small;**
}
```

Comment: browser developer tools, styles panel, computed tab, it says 13px.

Comment: @sdcr: I think it happened that you tested on a browser with scaling 1.2. See my answer below with a table. I'm not sure what is the value of keywords if they have `predefined` values and `don't change`. I think it makes sense for the keywords value to be `relative` to something so that it will be adjusted nicely based on the current context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the user agent.

From the book: [Pro Css techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059732X)

> The keywords provide relative font sizes to one another based on a
>   scaling factor of the user agent. This scaling factor is somewhat of a
>   moving target, as different user agents may provide different scaling
>   factors. Even the CSS specification changed its recommendation between
>   versions 1 and 2. (CSS 1 specified a scaling factor of 1.5 going up
>   and .66 going down, but changed to a more vague “between 1.0 and 1.2”
>   in the CSS 2 specification.)
>
> Because of this, the exact pixel sizes of rendered type vary from
>   browser to browser when size is specified using absolute-size
>   keywords. If we assume a default (medium) em square size of 16 pixels
>   (like most desktop browsers give us out of the box), we end up with
>   the following translations to pixel sizes for scaling factors of 1.5
>   and 1.2:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Jquery answer - `px`-`13px` `pt`-`9.75`

```js
alert('px :-' +$('p').css('font-size'))
alert('pt :-' +parseInt($('p').css('font-size'))*3/4)
```

```css
p{
    font-size:small;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text</p>
```